# AzureML Cannot create a deployment in endpoint p2b-sample-endpoint because it is in Creating provisioning state

Tags: azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

```
online_endpoint_name = "p2b-sample-endpoint"

# create an online endpoint
endpoint = ManagedOnlineEndpoint(
    name=online_endpoint_name,
    description="this is a sample online endpoint",
    auth_mode="key",
    tags={"foo": "bar"},

blue_deployment = ManagedOnlineDeployment(
    name="blue",
    endpoint_name=online_endpoint_name,
    model=model,
    environment=env,
    code_configuration=CodeConfiguration(
        code="./", scoring_script="score.py"
    ),
    instance_type="Standard_DS2_v2",
    instance_count=1,
)
)

ml_client.online_deployments.begin_create_or_update(blue_deployment)
```

HttpResponseError: (UserError) Cannot create a deployment in endpoint p2b-sample-endpoint because it is in Creating provisioning state.

Code: UserError
Message: Cannot create a deployment in endpoint p2b-sample-endpoint because it is in Creating provisioning state.

```
Additional Information:Type: ComponentName
Info: {
    "value": "managementfrontend"
}Type: Correlation
Info: {
    "value": {
        "operation": "295e1dadc1e11a2db8a470788ec6494f",
        "request": "adb9c5f973b580b9"
    }
}Type: Environment
Info: {
    "value": "westeurope"
}Type: Location
Info: {
    "value": "westeurope"
}Type: Time
Info: {
    "value": "2023-03-27T20:16:26.6786058+00:00"
}Type: InnerError
Info: {
    "value": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "EndpointNotReady",
            "innerError": null
        }
    }
}Type: MessageFormat
Info: {
    "value": "Cannot create a deployment in endpoint {endpointName} because it is in {state} provisioning state."
}Type: MessageParameters
Info: {
    "value": {
        "endpointName": "p2b-sample-endpoint",
        "state": "Creating"
    }
}
```

Also, no deployment logs found. folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere burried deepdown in the logs was gunicorn not found, I just had to make sure gunicorn was part part of requirements.txt and it worked